# Is it possible to use only certain values in a column when performing a pandas query

Tags: pandas, latitude-longitude, geopandas

I'm trying to use a post/zipcode map to plot Longitude/Latitude coordinated using GeoPandas.

If the post/zipcodes are sequential i.e. see below code, then I have no issues but there are some outlying post/zipcodes I'd like to use i.e 5118, 5371-3 but also redundant, 5354, as well as they are or are not required to be viewed on the map.

```
df_a = df.query('code >= 5350 & code <= 5355')
ax = df_a.plot()
```

Can I add or remove post/zipcodes within the one line of code above in a query?

[Map with marker points](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A6EV3.png)

Comment: it's not clear on what issue you are facing from, what is your expected output

Comment: @SL', when plotting the data, the underlying map is for post/zipcodes 5350 to 5355 of which I would like to remove 5354 as there are no marker points within. There are also marker points of some of the Long/Lat coordinates that are outside the mapped area so not within the shaded are of the map. If I am able to add code 5118 and remove 5354, I'll be well on my way.

I have added Map with Marker points to OP now

Comment: you could add more brackets and logical operators to obtain your target. for example as follows: `df.query("((code >= 5350 & code <= 5355) | (code >= 5371 & code <= 5373) | code == 5118) & (code != 5354)")`, however this gets messy very quickly, as you can see. I would instead create a list (e.g. using `range()`) and then filtering using `.loc` afterwards: `df_a = df.loc[df.code.isin(my_list)]`

Comment: @bexi much appreciated, issue resolved.